# Save Excel as PDF

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I open an Excel file in c#, make some changes and I want to save it as pdf file.
I have searched about it and find this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
oWB.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "D:\\xxxxx.pdf");
```

but this code sometimes opens a form and a printer must be selected! I don't know why?!

Is there any other way for exporting PDF from Excel?
I saw that Workbook.saveas() has a Fileformat object. How can we use it?

Comment: U can go with [this](https://sautinsoft.com/convert-excel-xls-to-pdf/xlsx-to-pdf-dotnet-csharp.php)

Comment: What is a Charp?

Comment: @Taw sorry csharp (C#) . i have missed 's'

Answer (score 0):

Check out **Spire.Xls**, below is the code for converting Excel to PDF.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");

//If you want to make the excel content fit to pdf page
//workbook.ConverterSetting.SheetFitToPage = true;

workbook.SaveToFile("result.pdf", Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
```

It has a free version which you can use without charge:
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-xls-component.html (Also available on NuGet)

Comment: I didn't know why someone vote not useful. This answer shows other way for exporting PDF from excel.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an alternative approach, then check out GemBox.Spreadsheet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Spreadsheet/

Here is how you can save Excel to PDF with it:

```
ExcelFile excel = ExcelFile.Load("D:\\xxxxx.xlsx");
excel.Save("D:\\xxxxx.pdf");
```

Or you can write it as following:

```
XlsxLoadOptions loadOptions = new XlsxLoadOptions();
ExcelFile excel = ExcelFile.Load("D:\\xxxxx.xlsx", loadOptions);

PdfSaveOptions saveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions();
excel.Save("D:\\xxxxx.pdf", saveOptions);
```

Comment: I didn't know why anyone vote not useful. This answer shows other way for exporting PDF from excel.

Answer (score -2):

Use iTextSharp.  It is native .NET code.  Doesn't require any Excel interop -

https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/

Comment: How can you save Excel to PDF with iTextSharp? To my understanding that library doesn't support reading Excel files....

Comment: @NixonUposseen I thought it would be obvious.  But you would just use https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/ first

Comment: Also, I was unable to find any build-in interoperability between these two libraries, have you accomplished this task with them? If yes, your answer currently lacks any decent information about how we can do that...

Answer (score -3):

You can do this using this API. Please see documentation for further detail.

http://cdn.bytescout.com/help/BytescoutPDFExtractorSDK/html/55590148-5bef-4338-ac16-1de4056a952b.htm

Comment: I think he wants to go the other way: save an Excel file as a PDF, not parse a PDF into Excel.

Comment: But I believe if he can explore the documentation, he will definitely find a solution there. As these packages provide both Excel to PDF and also PDF to excel. But the thing is he may explore. I am suggesting this because this API was a life savor for me when I stuck in the same type of issues. You can explore yourself, here is the link to that http://cdn.bytescout.com/help/BytescoutPDFSDK/index.html?_ga=2.60376301.1763457983.1520808212-62881910.1507833269